# Sorting HTML Table by Column Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, sorting, html-table

I am looking for someone to give me a hand with this problem:

We have a database filled with user's ranks, this data is pulled and put into a table like so (can't post an image):

| Name: | Rank: | Claims: | Last Seen: |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | Admin | 111 | Active Now |
| Test2 | Moderator | 213 | Active Now |
| Test3 | Senior Admin | 123 | Active Now |

[image: IMAGE HERE]

We basically want the 'Rank' Column to sort so that 'Senior Admin' is first, 'Admin' second and 'Moderator' last.

I have spent hours looking up ways to sort tables via sql sorting, php array sorting, javascript sorting etc. but cant find anything that doesn't sort alphabetically.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you generating the html for the table? It's hard to come up with an answer without knowing this.

Comment: You could just sort the array by that column and then print the html afterwards. It's a pretty simple solution actually. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sure your database will sort that data. Which database do you use?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP offers a custom sort function called `usort`. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for documentation.

It allows you to compare two objects using a custom comparison function. [W3Schools has a good tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_usort.asp) on how to get started making your own comparison function.

The `usort` function takes two parameters: the array you wish to sort, and the custom comparison function. For example, if you have an array of results called `$results`, you can define your comparison function like so:

```
function my_compare($person1, $person2) {
    if($person["rank"] == $person2["rank"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    elseif($person1["rank"] == "Senior Admin") { // Senior admin will always be at the top
        return -1; 
    }
    elseif($person2["rank"] == "Senior Admin") {
        return 1;
    }
    elseif($person1["rank"] == "Admin" && $person2["rank"] == "Moderator") {
        return -1;
    }
    elseif($person1["rank"] == "Moderator" && $person2["rank"] == "Admin") {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then, you can apply your sort by calling `usort($results, "my_compare");`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Edited to add clarity to the answer + added some example code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL to sort it the way you'd like. I don't know the structure of your SQL table - so I'm guessing - here's example working with MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(rank, 'Senior Admin,Admin,Moderator');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add another column, and assign each rank a level, then select and order them by level.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY level
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should consider this JQuery plugin. It easier to integrate and you can do lot of things with that. :)

http://datatables.net/index - Data tables.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it may be better that you bring your expertise to help resolve this problem

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. We typically do not answer overly broad questions and we certainly don't answer them with link only answers.